# Show only the first letter of the text (SwiftUi)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out how can I show only the first letter of the text?

```
struct MyText: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello")
            .lineLimit(1)
        
    }
}
```

This is how it should turn out

```
H
```

I tried using Line limit but as far as I know it only displays the text in one line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried to produce the first letter? What research have you done?

Comment: This question is so complex that more explanation is needed? I'm new and I'm looking for help

Comment: Just googling your title returns about 4,920,000 results. It has been answered before. Do your research before asking a question.

Comment: Strange, I searched, but for some reason I did not find the answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `String` has the `first` property which returns the first `Character` of the string. Now because `Character`s cannot be downcasted to `String`, here’s what you need to do:

```
let text = "Hello"

if let firstCharacter = text.first {
    Text(String(firstCharacter))
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: But if for example my text is missing then I get this error in console:  Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Exactly, because `first` is optional which means it can have no value. What `!` does is to force-unwrap `first`, meaning that it will try to give you its value and if it doesn’t have one it will try to give you something that doesn’t exist. Therefore it crashes. I updated my answer... have a look.

Answer (score -2):

This can be done using the [`first`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/first) property of the string:

```swift
"Hello".first
// -> "H"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to implement this (I'm new